# Quais propriedades CSS para específico background?

Tags: css

Estou a tentar desenhar um botão. Quero um background semelhante ao da imagem abaixo.
Começei por usar a propriedade border-radius, mas sem sucesso.

**[css]**

```
 .btn-criar{
                height: 50%;
                min-width: 60px;
                max-width: 100px;
                width: 80px;
                background-color: gray;
                position: relative;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: blue;
                border-width: 3px;
                border-radius: 50%; 

            }
```

**[HTML]**

```
<div class="row btn-criar">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <i class="btn-icon-criar fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <span class="btn-texto-criar">Criar</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Podem ajudar-me?

[image: ver exemplo]

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/365369/edit) sua pergunta e adicione o código que você tentou, assim será mais fácil que alguém o ajude.

Comment: @sant0will obrigado pela dica. Feito :)

Comment: Acho que você pode adicionar <span>'s dentro do botão para assim posicioná-los onde quiser e customizar seus layouts de forma independente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que acontece é que vc não tem um elemento que é um quadrado, mas sim um retângulo, isso faz com que o eixo de curvatura fique em forma de elipse e não de círculo, **já que a metade da largura não é igual a metade da altura.** Então colocar `border-radius: 50%;` não vai ficar como o esperado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para corrigir isso vc vai ter que colocar um valor de altura fixo para o seu botão, e ai sim usar o `border-radius` com um valor que seja proporcional a metade da altura.

Veja essa ideia no seu código, coloquei a altura do botão em `30px`, logo o `border-radius` fica com `15px`, metade da altura. Então vc precisa do mesmo valor no eixo X e Y por isso vc precisa de um valor fixo correspondente ao menor lado que no caso é a altura.

Como vc pode ver na imagem abaixo o **`50% de X é maior que 50% de Y`** por isso estava virando uma `elipse`...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT:** para agilizar criei uma variável no CSS para definir a altura do botão e no `border-radius` eu dividi essa `var()` por 2 com um `calc()` tipos assim: `border-radius: calc(var(--altura) / 2);`

```css
:root {
   --altura: 30px;
  }
 .btn-criar{
    height: var(--altura);
    min-width: 60px;
    max-width: 100px;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-radius: calc(var(--altura) / 2);
  }
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="row btn-criar">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <i class="btn-icon-criar fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <span class="btn-texto-criar">Criar</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Vc pode ler mais sobre essa propriedade aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

**OBS:** Pelas classes que vc está usando vi que vc está usando Bootstrap, mas pela organização do seu grid muito provavelmente vc vai ter problema com isso no futuro, fique atento na documentação do Bootstrap....

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Realmente funciona, gostaria de saber se não há alternativa para altura diâmica dinâmica.

Comment: @PedroCorreia Talvez tenha, mas não com berder-radius, vc pode até fazer algo mais automatizado usando CSS variables, como eu fiz no edite da minha resposta. Ou então vc pode fazer outros artifícios como usar pseudo elementos ou radial-gradiente, mas essas duas técnicas são mais avançadas... Leia o **EDIT** que deixei na resposta